# Row splitting in a dynamic HTML table using XSL and XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to split a loop using XSL in to a second row but am not sure how to approach this. Let me show you my code to explain.

**XML**

```
<main>
<book>
    <name>Harry Potter 1</name>
    <pages>347</pages>
    <authors>
        <name>J.K Rowling</name>
        <age>49</age>
    </authors>
    <authors>
        <name>Dan Brown</name>
        <age>59</age>
    </authors>
</book>
<book>
    <name>Harry Potter 2</name>
    <pages>800</pages>
    <authors>
        <name>J.K Rowling</name>
        <age>49</age>
    </authors>
    <authors>
        <name>Barack Obama</name>
        <age>40</age>
    </authors>
</book>
```

**XSL**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" border="1">
<xsl:for-each select="main/book">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="pages" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="./authors">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="age" /></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Currently this outputs something like this.

[image]

What I would like to accomplish is something like this

[image]

As you can see the authors are not stacked below each other and not next to each other.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you for reading.

Comment: The output you show is NOT the output that is received using your code: you only have one row per book, not two.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sorry adjusted code to match result.

Comment: You just need to move the 2nd opening `<tr>` tag inside the inner `<xsl:for-each>` -  as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested output does not seem to make much sense (mixing book and author names in the same column, as well as number of pages and author's age), but can be easily achieved using:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table class="table table-bordered" border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="main/book">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="pages" /></td>
            </tr>   
            <xsl:for-each select="authors">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="age" /></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table> 
</xsl:template>
```